# how do I get a batch file to accept input from a txt file to run wmic commands on multiple machines

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I have a batch file with multiple WMIC commands and I want to be able to pull host names I saved in a text file to run these commands for multiple machines. any thoughts?

this is my code so far, however it only pulls my machines information, now i would like to add a list of other machines

thank you in advance

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if exist C:\dell\%computername%.csv del C:\dell\%computername%.csv"
    set outputfile="C:\dell\%computername%.csv"


    hostname>>%outputfile%

    wmic Cpu get Name>>%outputfile%

    wmic path win32_VideoController get name>>%outputfile%

    wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory>>%outputfile%

    WMIC LOGICALDISK where drivetype=3 get caption,size,FreeSpace>%~n0.tmp



    for /f "tokens=1-3 skip=1" %%a in ('type "%~n0.tmp"') do call 
    :displayinfo %%a %%b %%c
    exit /b


    :displayinfo
    set drive=%1
    set free=%2
    set total=%3


    call :convertbytes total
    call :convertbytes free

    echo %drive% Total: %total%. Free: %free%>>C:\dell\%computername%.csv


    :convertbytes
    set str=!%1!
    set "sign="
    set bytes=0
    set fraction=0

    :loop
    set fraction=%bytes:~0,1%
    set bytes=%str:~-3%
    set str=%str:~0,-3%
    if "%sign%"=="GB" set sign=TB
    if "%sign%"=="MB" set sign=GB
    if "%sign%"=="KB" set sign=MB
    if "%sign%"=="B" set sign=KB
    if not defined sign set sign=B
    if defined str goto loop
    set %1=%bytes%.%fraction% %sign%

    goto :eof
```

Comment: WMIC has a `/NODE` option to give it a file name with a list of computers you need to run commands on.

Comment: ... it also has `/Append` and `/Output` options; enter `WMIC /?` at the Command Prompt for the command usage information.